# python "print" doesn't work after sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Tags: python, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display utf-8 in windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578685/how-to-display-utf-8-in-windows-console)

python "print" statement doesn't work.

To avoid this error,

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I put a few statements in my code as below

```
import sys

reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

before the code, "print" works well. However, after the code, "print" doesn't work.

```
print "A"

import sys

reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

print "B"
```

Here, only "A" printed on my computer, Python2.7.3 (64bit) for Windows. Python2.7 IDLE

I need help

Comment: `sys.setdefaultencoding` is removed from `sys` once the `site` module is imported.  This is documented and is done for a reason.  You can't use `sys.defaultencoding` this way.  See the linked question.

Comment: Actually, I solved this problem by using Aptana Studio 3 instead of using IDLE. It might be because default encoding settings are different each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sys.setdefaultencoding` is removed for a reason by `site` and you shouldn't use `reload(sys)` to restore it. Instead, my solution would be to do nothing, Python automatically detects encoding basing on ENV LANG variable or Windows `chcp` encoding.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
>>> os.environ["LANG"]
'pl_PL.UTF-8'
>>> print u"\xabtest\xbb"
«test»
>>>
```

But that could cause issues when encoding doesn't have characters you want. You should instead try degrading gracefully - the chance of displaying characters you want is close to 0 (so you should try using pure-ASCII version, or use Unidecode to show usable output (or simply fail)). You could try catching exception and printing basic version of string instead.

```
$ LANG=C python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
>>> os.environ["LANG"]
'C'
>>> print u"\xabtest\xbb"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

But there is problem called Windows that has problems with Unicode support. While technically `chcp 65001` should work, it doesn't actually work unless you're using Python 3.3. Python uses portable `stdio.h`, but `cmd.exe` expects Windows specific calls, like `WriteConsoleW()`. Only 8-bit encodings work reliably (such as CP437), really.

The workaround would be to use other terminal that supports Unicode properly, such as Cygwin's console or IDLE included with Python.