# Encoding fail in Python after parsing RSS

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, rss, feedparser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display utf-8 in windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578685/how-to-display-utf-8-in-windows-console)

After parsing an RSS-feed using the feedparser package, I get an error when trying to print the title:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
   return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 73: character maps to <undefined>
```

After using .encode() to encode it to UTF-8 I get no error, but I do get weird characters in the output:

> Anyone can add services to your BT account with just basic information
>   ΓÇô and BT isnΓÇÖt worried

What am I doing wrong, do I have to encode it differently?

Comment: probably you need to decode it first

Comment: Your Windows terminal cannot handle these characters. You'll need to switch your terminal to accept UTF-8. Not an easy task, from what I have heard so far.