# Getting a raw string from a unicode string in python

Tags: unicode, python-2.7

I have a Unicode string I'm retrieving from a web service in python.

I need to access a URL I've parsed from this string, that includes various diacritics.

However, if I pass the unicode string to `urlllib2`, it produces a unicode encoding error. The **exact same** string, as a "raw" string `r"some string"` works properly.

How can I get the raw binary representation of a unicode string in python, without converting it to the system locale?

I've been through the python docs, and every thing seems to come back to the `codecs` module. However, the documentation for the `codecs` module is sparse at best, and the whole thing seems to be extremely file oriented.

---

I'm on windows, if it's important.

Comment: Pro tip: when encountering a Python error, include the *full* traceback and error message in your question. That reduces the amount of guessing we have to do *dramatically*.

Comment: I want to know *exactly* what is causing the error. You may know, but I am not so sure. Convince me.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. Python will, by default, encode to ASCII any unicode value you are trying to treat as raw bytes, by concatenating it with other bytes, for example. The work-around is to *encode* it to bytes first. The proper encoding depends on the context; for the domain name it's IDNA, for path parts it's UTF-8, etc.

Comment: Really, really, really read the articles I linked before you continue.

Comment: I had read the Python Unicode HOWTO before I even posted my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are not showing that you are understanding the differences. Have you read the Joel on Software article? I cannot stress enough that you need to understand what encoding really means, and that you need to understand that you *have* to pick an encoding in order to use files or network services, and that there is no such thing as raw unicode bytes. There is *always* an encoding.

Comment: Oh crap, I'm making a prat of myself. I keep saying unicode, and thinking UTF-8. I'm an idiot. WTF. Sorry

Comment: On the other hand, I think I just solved my problem, at least in part. The whole thing only works because the text file was saved as UTF-8.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Also, I apologise for getting snippy.

Comment: No problem! Glad you worked out your problem!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - On the other hand, I think I've found a bug in `urllib2`. In a file saved with UTF-8 encoding: `urllib2.urlopen("http://✪df.ws" )` works, and `urllib2.urlopen(u"http://✪df.ws")` does not.

Comment: Unicode values for URLs are *not supported*, encode first. The particular example you give uses a unicode character in the domain name, and depending on the source encoding you specified for the python file the raw string you provide could have *any* encoding; in a terminal it depends on the terminal encoding. And the `r` is redundant, it's just another way of spelling out a bytestring where the backslash doesn't from an escape code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - They're not? That's not mentioned anywhere in the python docs, at least. Assuming UTF-8 urls are supported (and they seem to work, so I think that's a safe assumption), it seems a bit odd  for a library to not accept a object containing a valid URL string, when it just needs to be encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Are there unicode characters that don't fit in UTF-8? Edit: not according to wikipedia.

Comment: Note that the `unicode` type is a relatively late addition to Python, so a lot of documentation doesn't mention it explicitly. If you get UnicodeDecodeError exceptions, it's a safe bet that it's not supported. There are code points in Unicode that UTF-8 is not *supposed* to encode (notably the UTF-16 surrogate halves U+D800 through U+DFFF), and codepoints over U+1FFFFF are officially off-limits to UTF-8. Python can only deal with unicode points up to U+10FFFF in any case, so that's not going to be a problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I see. Anyways, it seems I was bitten by a confluence of factors. Mostly, my test harnesses were producing wierd results because they were *already* UTF-8 encoded, as that is the file encoding I was using. That and the fact that since I'm on windows, I can't print *any* characters to the terminal that are not straight ascii, and I wound up all twisted in knots trying to figure out where my encoding was changing.

Comment: I think I'll see if I can hack unicode url support into urllib, and bug the python people to see if they're interested.

Comment: See [How to display utf-8 in windows console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3578685) on how to print UTF-8 to the console..

Comment: I doubt the python people are interested in patching up `urllib` in Python 2.x. 2.7 is the end of the line for Python 2.x, and `urllib` has been refactored in Python 3 already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *encode* the URL from unicode to a bytestring. `u''` and `r''` produce two *different* kinds of objects; a unicode string and a bytestring.

You can encode a unicode string to bytecode with the `.encode()` method, but you need to know what encoding to use. Usually, for URLs, UTF-8 is great, but you do need to *escape* the bytes to fit the URL scheme as well:

```
import urlparse, urllib

parts = list(urlparse.urlsplit(url))
parts[2] = urllib.quote(parts[2].encode('utf8'))
url = urlparse.urlunsplit(parts)
```

The above example is based on an educated guess that the problem you are facing is due to non-ASCII characters in the path part of the URL, but without further details from you it has to remain a guess.

For domain names, you need to apply the [IDNA RFC3490 encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html):

```
parts = list(urlparse.urlsplit(url))
parts[1] = parts[1].encode('idna')
parts = [p.encode('utf8') if isinstance(p, unicode) else p for p in parts]
url = urlparse.urlunsplit(parts)
```

See the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more information. I also *strongly* recommend you read the [Joel on Software Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) as a good primer on the subject of encodings.

Comment: You *really* need to read the Unicode howto and the Joel on Software article. *There are no underlying bytes, only character codepoints*. You *have* to encode to bytes using the `.encode()` method.