# How to write unicode japanese from a file to another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-unicode

I have some json files and there're some places with encoded japanese like `\u672c\u30fb\u96d1\u8a8c\u30fb\u66f8\u7c4d\u60c5\u5831` in the files, and I want to decode them into japanese.

The problem is when I use this method:

```
text = '\u672c\u30fb\u96d1\u8a8c\u30fb\u66f8\u7c4d\u60c5\u5831'
print(text)
```

And it printed

```
本・雑誌・書籍情報
```

But when I read it directly from file, for example, the prepared file is index.json and its content is just:

```
\u672c\u30fb\u96d1\u8a8c\u30fb\u66f8\u7c4d\u60c5\u5831
```

and the method I used is

```
file = open('index.json','r')
text = file.read()
print(text)
```

and it just printed

```
\u672c\u30fb\u96d1\u8a8c\u30fb\u66f8\u7c4d\u60c5\u5831
```

One thing I found kinda wierd is that when I tried to print:

```
print(file.read())
print(text)
```

The `file.read()` returns nothing, even with `file.read(1)`.

Edit: I found out that the main problem is when you write `text = '\u672c'`, python would recognize `\u672c` as a single character. But when you read from a file, then it would recognize it as a string with 6 characters. Anyway to convert it?

Comment: Its an encoding problem have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682933/chinese-and-japanese-character-support-in-python

Comment: But does that work with python 3 too?

Comment: @pruggg. The file contains the string `'\\u672c`, not `'\u672c'`. That's pretty version independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Let's say that your file contains the following (literal) text:

```
\u672c\u30fb\u96d1\u8a8c\u30fb\u66f8\u7c4d\u60c5\u5831
```

You could represent this in Python as either

```
text = '\\u672c\\u30fb\\u96d1\\u8a8c\\u30fb\\u66f8\\u7c4d\\u60c5\\u5831'
```

OR

```
text = r'\u672c\u30fb\u96d1\u8a8c\u30fb\u66f8\u7c4d\u60c5\u5831'
```

To convert the literal escapes into the Unicode characters they represent, you need to decode them properly:

```
text.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

results in

```
本・雑誌・書籍情報
```

The reason that `file.read()` and `file.read(1)` did not work for you is that a file does not automatically rewind. Once you read in the file, it's at the end until you manually rewind it or close and reopen it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I am looking for!