# Incorrect appearance of encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, rpc

```
from jsonrpclib import jsonrpc

url = 'https://myserver.com:443'
jpc = jsonrpc.Server('%s/jsonrpc' % url)
new_string = "金衣大俠"
jpc.editqueue("NewName", new_string, 123)
```

The `new_string` appears as `Ñc'à` in my server.  The server supports foreign characters, if I copy the text in `new_string` I can paste and save it in the server through the UI (not using jsonrpc) and it appears just fine.  I would guess I have to encode my string a certain way for this to work.  Any ideas on how I can encode my string for it to work ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chinese and Japanese character support in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682933/chinese-and-japanese-character-support-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify:

> encode my string *in a certain way

You can use inbuilt string `encode` / `decode` function.

```
new_string = u'金衣大俠' #force it to unicode

# On the client side:
encoded_string = new_string.encode('utf-16')

# and on the server side:
decoded_string = received_string.decode('utf-16')
```

Comment: I have no control over server decoding.  I tried encoding utf-16, appeared as ` x00` on the server.  I was looking for some guesses on what decoding the server is using (so I know how to encode) based on the mapping of "金衣大俠" to "Ñc'à"

Answer (score 0):

Python encoding has been answered in a different stack exchange already. Kindly reference the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682933/chinese-and-japanese-character-support-in-python) and define new_string on line 5 appropriately

Comment: I have no control over server decoding. I tried encoding utf-16 appeared as ` x00` on the server. I was looking for some guesses on what decoding the server is using (so I know how to encode) based on the mapping of "金衣大俠" to "Ñc'à"  utf-8 and utf-16 both failed.