# unicodeescape error when importing a CSV File in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

It's a very basic question but I've tried many things. My last code is:

```
import csv
with open ('C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Desktop\Base de dados para curso de Python/enrollments.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV =csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in readCSV:
        print(row)
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-9-3103e7dc9e55>", line 3
    with open ('C:\Users\Michel Spiero\Desktop\Base de dados para curso de Python/enrollments.csv') as csvfile:
              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

What Should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089210/2237916 in order to check if is the problem with the encoding of the ipython you are using.

Comment: Use a raw string `r'c:\Users\...'` if you have backslashes in your string, or use double backslashes to escape them, or use forward slashes.  The `\U` is the start of a Unicode escape sequence otherwise, as the error message says.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347854/235698

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unicode Error "unicodeescape" codec can't decode bytes... Cannot open text files in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash U (`\U`) has a special meaning in string literals. [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in the documentation says for `\Uxxxxxxxx` the meaning is *„Character with 32-bit hex value xxxxxxxx“*.

So you have to escape at least the backslash before the U of Users, or put an `r` in front of the string so no backslash has a special meaning.